# Python threading and socket issue when trying to control a Robot

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm facing an issue while using Python 3.8.11, threading and socket packages to control a robot that moves on X/Y axes. I'm under Windows 10.

**Summary of the code:**
I use socket to estabish the connection between my python interface and the server (the robot). The robot needs to be send an alive message/command constantly (at least every 2 seconds) so that the connection is maintained. I therefore use threading to do so, by defining a function that will send an alive message to the robot in a separate thread, every second.

I have alse defined another separate thread to operate basic initialization commands on the robot, before starting a while loop that runs movement commands on the robots (same movement command is sent to the robot until I want it to stop).

I have a third thread that look for a stop instruction to stop the threads and connection to the robot (when I press the key q on my keyboard).

**Code:**

```
import threading  # to handle multiple threads operating in parallel
import time  # to handle time events
import socket  # to connect Python client to TCP IP server
import keyboard  # to handle keyboard events

# TCP IP parameters of the Server
HOST = '192.168.3.11'
PORT = 3920

# Initializing the Client/Server connection
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_address = (HOST, PORT)
sock.connect(server_address)

# Initializing the Alive message to keep the Client/Server connection alive (message need to be sent at least every 2 seconds otherwise connection is lost)
messageAliveJog = "CRISTART 1234 ALIVEJOG 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 CRIEND"
encodedAliveJog=messageAliveJog.encode('utf-8')
arrayAliveJog=bytearray(encodedAliveJog)

# Initializing the movement message that will be iterated
messageMoveGantryRelative_10x10 = "CRISTART 1234 CMD Move RelativeJoint 10 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 30 CRIEND"
encodedMoveGantryRelative_10x10=messageMoveGantryRelative_10x10.encode('utf-8')
arrayMoveGantryRelative_10x10=bytearray(encodedMoveGantryRelative_10x10)

# Initializing the Stop Thread variable
stop_threads = False


# Function to keep Client Server connection alive
def connectGantry():
    while True:
        global arrayAliveJog
        print('Sending Alive')
        sock.sendall(arrayAliveJog)
        # data = sock.recv(1024)
        # print(data)
        time.sleep(1)
        global stop_threads
        if stop_threads:
            break

# Function to initiate the robot first moves, and then to iterate the same movement again and again
def moveGantry():
    # Command 1: resetting the robot
    messageResetGantry = "CRISTART 1234 CMD Reset CRIEND"
    encodedResetGantry = messageResetGantry.encode('utf-8')
    arrayResetGantry=bytearray(encodedResetGantry)
    print("Resetting Gantry")
    sock.sendall(arrayResetGantry)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # Command 2: Enabling robot motors
    messageEnableMotors = "CRISTART 1234 CMD Enable CRIEND"
    encodedEnableMotors=messageEnableMotors.encode('utf-8')
    arrayEnableMotors=bytearray(encodedEnableMotors)
    print("Enabling Motors")
    sock.sendall(arrayEnableMotors)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # Command 3: Forcing Python client to be pritority client to the Robot
    messageSetClientActive = "CRISTART 1234 CMD SetActive true CRIEND"
    encodedSetClientActive=messageSetClientActive.encode('utf-8')
    arraySetClientActive=bytearray(encodedSetClientActive)
    print("Activating Client")
    sock.sendall(arraySetClientActive)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # Command 4: Moving the robot near its 0 location (X = 5 and Y  = 5 here)
    messageMoveGantryTo_5x5 = "CRISTART 1234 CMD Move Joint 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 30 CRIEND"
    encodedMoveGantryTo_5x5=messageMoveGantryTo_5x5.encode('utf-8')
    arrayMoveGantryTo_5x5=bytearray(encodedMoveGantryTo_5x5)
    print("Moving Gantry to Location 10x10")
    sock.sendall(arrayMoveGantryTo_5x5)
    time.sleep(10)

    # Command 5: Referencing Robot X and Y axes
    messageReferenceAxes = "CRISTART 1234 CMD ReferenceAllJoints CRIEND"
    encodedReferenceAxes=messageReferenceAxes.encode('utf-8')
    arrayReferenceAxes=bytearray(encodedReferenceAxes)
    print("Referencing Joints")
    sock.sendall(arrayReferenceAxes)
    time.sleep(30)

    # Command 6: Making sure the robot motors are still enabled after referencing
    messageEnableMotors = "CRISTART 1234 CMD Enable CRIEND"
    encodedEnableMotors=messageEnableMotors.encode('utf-8')
    arrayEnableMotors=bytearray(encodedEnableMotors)
    print("Enabling Motors")
    sock.sendall(arrayEnableMotors)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # Command 7: Defining the Robot motion type
    messageMotionTypeJoint = "CRISTART 1234 CMD MotionTypeJoint CRIEND"
    encodedMotionTypeJoint=messageMotionTypeJoint.encode('utf-8')
    arrayMotionTypeJoint=bytearray(encodedMotionTypeJoint)
    print("Defining Motion Type to Joint")
    sock.sendall(arrayMotionTypeJoint)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # Command 8: Moving the Robot to its starting position
    messageMoveGantryTo_10x10 = "CRISTART 1234 CMD Move Joint 100 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 30 CRIEND"
    encodedMoveGantryTo_10x10=messageMoveGantryTo_10x10.encode('utf-8')
    arrayMoveGantryTo_10x10=bytearray(encodedMoveGantryTo_10x10)
    print("Moving Gantry to Location 10x10")
    sock.sendall(arrayMoveGantryTo_10x10)
    time.sleep(10)

    # Command 9: Starting the Loop during which the Robot will sequentially move by 10mm on the X axis and 10mm on the Y axis
    counterIndex = 1
    while True:
        global arrayMoveGantryRelative_10x10
        print("Moving Gantry by 10x10mm")
        sock.sendall(arrayMoveGantryRelative_10x10)
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Stop number: ", counterIndex)
        counterIndex += 1
        # Exiting Loop if stop_threads gets True (when key q is pressed)
        if stop_threads:
            break

# Stopping the threads if key q is pressed
def stopTheThreads():
    global stop_threads
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if keyboard.read_key() == "q":
            stop_threads = True
            break

# Initializing the Threads
t1 = threading.Thread(target = connectGantry)
t2 = threading.Thread(target = moveGantry)
t3 = threading.Thread(target = stopTheThreads)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()


# Waiting for Thread 1 (alive message) to be ended before closing the Client/Server sock connection
t1.join()
print('Ending Connection')
sock.close()
```

When running this code, the connection between python interface and the robot is made, then the robot initializes properly and start looping over the movement command (moving step by step, every 5 seconds, by 10mm on the X and Y axes). However, after 5 to 10 iterations of this within the while loop, I face this error message:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\EnvName\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\EnvName\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:/Foldername/MoveGantry.py", line 114, in moveGantry
    sock.sendall(arrayMoveGantryRelative_10x10)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

This error never really occurs at the same step (sometimes the error mentions line 82 in moveGantry rather than line 114 as in the above example), nor after the same number of iterations of the while loop (sometimes 5 iterations, sometimes 6, sometimes up to 10).

As I'm pretty new to threading and socket connections, it's likely that I've done mistakes when defining/parameterizing threads and sockets. It is challenging though for me to understand why this error occurs after some time while everything goes well for the first iterations. I hope someone will be able to navigate me through this issue.

Comment: Just for future reference, you only need a `global` statement if you are replacing the value of the item.  Here, the one in `stopTheThreads` is the only one you need.

Comment: Do you see the "Ending Connection" message before it dies?  Are you wired to the robot, or is it wireless?  Does your robot have a socket timeout?  Is it possible you are losing the connection?

Comment: Tip: When you ask a question on SO, please try to make it a [mcve]. By reducing the code down to only what is necessary to reproduce your problem, you make it easier for others to help resolve your issue.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes I see "Ending Connection message before it dies. I am wired to the robot (ethernet), the robot has a socket timeout of 2 seconds (that is why I send an alive message every second. Note that sending it every 0.5 sec does not solve the issue). I don't think losing the connection is the issue, but I have contacted the robot support in parallel to ensure this (with the log files of the robot). Thanks for info about global, good to know for the future. To SuperStormer: OK sorry, I'll edit the code to make it easier for others.

Comment: Well, if you see "Ending Connection", that means your `connectGantry` thread has exited.  That's the problem you need to chase.

Comment: Actually, I've navigated the terminal and sometimes "Ending Connection" is printed before the error, sometimes it's printed after the error, so it looks like there is some conflict between my multiple threads which are sending messages to the same socket. Sometimes thread 1 causes the issue, sometimes it's thread 2. So it's very likely a multithread/socket issue, which stop the thread, therefore causing "Ending connection" to be printed.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the socket module is thread safe. At least not in a way that you can use the same socket from multiple threads. Try using [queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) or something that is thread safe to have sort of a buffer of commands you want to send to the robot. You can then safely put commands into that buffer from multiple thread and actually only send all the commands from one thread.

Comment: You would be wrong.  The socket module is all Python, which in inherently thread-safe. and the C code doesn't really need to be thread-safe until it gets into the kernel, which is thread-safe.  Remember, the buffering is all done in the kernel's network code, not in Python.

Comment: Thank you for the Queue suggestion, I have actually implemented it as it makes sense to me to run the command to the robot that way (multiple threads are filling the queue, and one thread is separately navigating this queue and is the only one sending the messages to the robot). However this does not solve my issue. I feel now that the issue comes from a loss of connection caused by the robot, and so not a code issue. Still investigating this though. Tahnk you for the help anyway.